# $\dim R$=$\sup\{\dim R_f|f\in R\}$

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

we wrote in a comment in our script the following:

> If $R$ is a ring: $\dim R=\sup\{\dim R_f\mid f\in R\}$.

We defined: $R_f:=(\{f^n|n\in\mathbb{N}\})^{-1}R$

We didn't prove this. Should this be obvious? Can someone explain why this is true? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\dim R$ as in Krull dimension?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Well, for invertible $f$ your localization $R_f$ is just $R$, right? And since localization cannot increase dimension then the equality is trivially true? So do you assume that the supremum is taken over non-invertible elements?

Comment: Why can localizations not increase the dimension? It seems obvious to me, but I don't know how to prove it. Also why does $R_f$ equal $R$ if $f$ is invertible? Is it because there is an isomorphism $g:(\{f^n|n\in\mathbb{N}\})^{-1}R\rightarrow R$ with $(r,f)\mapsto r*f^{-1}$?

Comment: Because there is 1-1 correspondence between prime ideals of $S^{-1}R$ and prime ideals of $R$ and this correspondence preserves inclusions. So every chain in $S^{-1}R$ corresponds to a chain in $R$. As for the other question: yes, this the isomorphism.

Comment: Nevermind I understood the first part.